# Glusterfs, gluster volume status command shows tcp port n/a status

Tags: glusterfs

Raised network storage based on glusterfs, on which I created three volumes for storing application data. After executing the gluster volume start <name_volume> force command, I checked the status of the volumes and saw that the tcp port was in the "n / a" status.

```
 gluster volume status
Status of volume: logz
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick 10.130.0.9:/log_data/brick2           N/A       N/A        N       N/A

Task Status of Volume logz
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks

Status of volume: nextcloud
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick 10.130.0.9:/nex_data/brick1           N/A       N/A        N       N/A

Task Status of Volume nextcloud
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks

Status of volume: prometheus
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick 10.130.0.9:/promet_data/brick3        N/A       N/A        N       N/A

Task Status of Volume prometheus
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

```
gluster volume info

Volume Name: logz
Type: Distribute
Volume ID: 7340977f-bae8-4c9a-9d5e-3a462b0eea34
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: 10.130.0.9:/log_data/brick2
Options Reconfigured:
nfs.disable: on
storage.fips-mode-rchecksum: on
transport.address-family: inet

Volume Name: nextcloud
Type: Distribute
Volume ID: 7cfd5606-08b6-4326-ba6a-0dba595b3ae0
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: 10.130.0.9:/nex_data/brick1
Options Reconfigured:
nfs.disable: on
storage.fips-mode-rchecksum: on
transport.address-family: inet

Volume Name: prometheus
Type: Distribute
Volume ID: fd2e819c-111a-4368-806f-1395cc48956e
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: 10.130.0.9:/promet_data/brick3
Options Reconfigured:
nfs.disable: on
storage.fips-mode-rchecksum: on
transport.address-family: inet
```

```
ss -tunlp
Netid     State      Recv-Q     Send-Q           Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port     Process
udp       UNCONN     0          0                127.0.0.53%lo:53                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=483,fd=12))
udp       UNCONN     0          0              10.130.0.9%eth0:68                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-network",pid=481,fd=19))
udp       UNCONN     0          0                      0.0.0.0:111                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("rpcbind",pid=455,fd=5),("systemd",pid=1,fd=78))
udp       UNCONN     0          0                         [::]:111                   [::]:*         users:(("rpcbind",pid=455,fd=7),("systemd",pid=1,fd=80))
tcp       LISTEN     0          1024                   0.0.0.0:24007              0.0.0.0:*         users:(("glusterd",pid=8081,fd=10))
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                   0.0.0.0:111                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("rpcbind",pid=455,fd=4),("systemd",pid=1,fd=77))
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096             127.0.0.53%lo:53                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=483,fd=13))
tcp       LISTEN     0          128                    0.0.0.0:22                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("sshd",pid=564,fd=3))
tcp       LISTEN     0          128                  127.0.0.1:6010               0.0.0.0:*         users:(("sshd",pid=737,fd=11))
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                      [::]:111                   [::]:*         users:(("rpcbind",pid=455,fd=6),("systemd",pid=1,fd=79))
tcp       LISTEN     0          128                       [::]:22                    [::]:*         users:(("sshd",pid=564,fd=4))
tcp       LISTEN     0          128                      [::1]:6010                  [::]:*         users:(("sshd",pid=737,fd=10))
```

On github they write that this can be fixed. "Solution: glusterd should check errno set by runner_run()
, and if it's set to EADDRINUSE it should allocate a new
port to the brick and try to start it again.", but it is not indicated in which file it needs to be fixed. Can you tell me how to solve the problem so that all my created volumes can rise on different ports. I tried to remove glusterfs-server and reinstall it, and after of this, even the first volume that worked on port 49152 became unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

commented out the option max-port line in the glusterd.vol file, then restarted the service and created the volumes again, as a result, each volume was raised on a separate tcp port